# SQL Query - Finding a difference between 2 values in same table

Tags: sql, difference, oracle-xe

I need help with a specific query involving one of my databases.

```
Name           Elev    Difficulty  Map         Region
----------------------------------------------------------
Pilot Knob(S)   6200    2       Oynx          Southern Sierra
Spanish Needle  12322   3       Lament Peak   Southern Sierra
Lamont Peak     7429    2       Lament Peak   Southern Sierra
South Guard     13232   2       Mt Brewer     Great Western Divide
Mount Brewer    13570   2       Mt Brewer     Great Western Divide
North Guard     13327   4       Mt Brewer     Great Western Divide
Midway Mountain 11284   2       Mt Brewer     Great Western Divide
```

I need to find which maps have more than 2000 foot difference between the highest and lowest peaks?

Not to sure on I would use the MIN() and MAX() functions to figure this out.
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And a hint:  Use the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I have different solution for you but I can't unless you tag the database you are using.

Comment: Using oracle express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track with MIN and MAX. You just need to apply them over a grouping of the maps. Something like this:

```
SELECT Map 
FROM 
    Table 
GROUP BY  
    Map
HAVING 
    MAX(Elev) - MIN(Elev) > 2000
ORDER BY
    MAX(Elev) - MIN(Elev)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfect.

Comment: Glad it helped! Remember to mark as an answer if you don't need more answers given.

Comment: Is there anyway to list the results in least to greatest order??

Comment: Yep - see the edit. Default sort order is ascending, so this will list the results from the row with the smallest difference in elevation to the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation (I've demonstrated writing in T-SQL below. You need to aggregate the maps into groups, then evaluate these based on the maximum and minimum values within these groupings.

```
--//We're grouping by map and demonstrating the max and min values returned
select Map, max (elev) as MaxElev, min (elev) as MinElev
from targettable
group by map;

--//We then need to filter the group and only return when the difference is
--//Greater than 2000
select map,  max (elev) as MaxElev, min (elev) as MinElev
from targettable
group by map
having (Max (elev) - 2000) > min (Elev);

--//Or alternatively you can use subtract values and compare

select map,  max (elev) as MaxElev, min (elev) as MinElev
from targettable
group by map
having (max (elev) - min (elev)) > 2000;

--//We can then tidy up and add an order if required (descending shown)

select map
from targettable
group by map
having (max (elev) - min (elev)) > 2000
order by max(elev);
```